# Grossly use space to run faster, inline everything?

Tags: performance, assembly, diskspace

I do a fair amount of assembly language programming and I find myself increasingly using redundant code in order to increase runtime speed.

For example, I have a routine that converts a numeric ASCII string to an integer which is about 40 lines long. However, of those 40 lines, 12 are clears, pushes and pops used to manage arguments to the subroutine. If I inline this routine, then most of these instructions go away, plus there are is no CALL and no RET, two more instructions that do not have to be executed. Overall the routine runs about 30% faster if it is inlined. The drawback (besides using more space) is that the routine has to be hardwired to local register assignments, so it is a little different each time it is inlined.

Considering how much disk and memory space is available nowadays, I am considering inlining everything. This might turn a 500k program into a 3M program, but who cares? If it runs 25% faster, then it is a tangible benefit. People seem to care more about responsiveness than how much disk space a program is using. Also, my programs tend to be pretty compact assembly language programs, not OO-bloatware anyway.

Am I missing any hidden gotchas here, or should I just go whole hog and become the inline macro monster?

Comment: If performance is what you're after then I'd say go for it, as that's one of the main advantages of using inline assembly. Also if the disk space is a concern you could possibly compress the resulting program by "packing" it in some way...

Comment: Inlining is not bad, but inlining assembly manually? What if you have to change a routine inlined 30 times already? Will you be able to still read the code fluently after inlining? In short: readability and maintainability. Maybe try to invest in more convenient ways to pass parameters. In a full-fledged program usually the code is the smaller of the assets anyway, so space should not be a problem.

Comment: Keep profiling, once you will bloat the code too much, the cache hits by satiating the cache with code+data may bring the performance down. Also it's sort of rare to run most of the app code all the time, it's more like only about 10-30% of code needs any optimization at all, unless you work on something specific.

Comment: Don't know whether I really see the need to inline a String2Int function. I could imagine graphics and maybe other real-time stuff to be worth inlining, but code that builds numbers from keyboard input? Really? Also: "inline macro monster" sounds like asking for premature optimization to me...

Comment: Trying to be more consistent in register use, or sacrifice just a bit of speed for some register swapping, and leverage a macro to inline things seems the way to go.